# Variables in XPATH expression in XSLT1

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I was previously using XSLT 2.0 for this but decided to make it XSLT 1.0 compatible for certain reasons and from what I've read/found out, variables don't work in XPATH expressions in XSLT 1.0.

This was the original XSL that I used in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="footnote_ref">
  <xsl:variable as="xs:integer" name="ref" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="fid" select="generate-id(../following-sibling::footnote_list[1]/footnote[$ref])"/>
  <sup><a href="#{$fid}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </a></sup>
</xsl:template>
```

For citation `n` it will link to the `n`th footnote in the next footnote section.

In XSLT 1.0 this doesn't work, it seems to ignore the `[$ref]` part and just link to the first footnote regardless. I thought that [`dyn:evaluate`](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html) from EXSLT would work so I tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="fid" select="dyn:evaluate('generate-id(../following-sibling::footnote_list[1]/footnote[$ref])')"/>
```

If I understand correctly, this should evaluate to `generate-id(../following-sibling::footnote_list[1]/footnote[$ref])` but with `$ref` substituted. In the [example](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html) they show using variables just fine but this still doesn't work and behaves just like without the `dyn:evaluate`, ignoring the variable entirely.

Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding `dyn:evaluate`? If it matters I'm using libxslt through lxml (Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In XSLT 1.0 this doesn't work, it seems to ignore the `[$ref]` part and just link to the first footnote regardless.

XSLT 1.0 doesn't support the `as` attribute on `xsl:variable`.  So in the following:

```
<xsl:template match="footnote_ref">
  <xsl:variable name="ref" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="fid" select="generate-id(../following-sibling::footnote_list[1]/footnote[$ref])"/>
  <sup><a href="#{$fid}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </a></sup>
</xsl:template>
```

`$ref` is a node set and thus the final predicate in `footnote[$ref]` says "choose all `footnote` elements such that the node set `$ref` is not empty" (i.e. all of them).  And when you pass a set of nodes to `generate-id` you get back the ID of the *first* node in the set in document order.  But if you say

```
  <xsl:variable name="ref" select="number(.)"/>
```

then `$ref` is a number, and the predicate will do the `position()` based test you require and you should get the correct footnote.